# R How to find the most frequent combinations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a customer dataset df that looks like this

```
ID | Item |
1  | A    |
1  | B    |
1  | C    |
2  | A    |
2  | B    |
2  | B    |
3  | A    |
3  | B    |
3  | C    |
4  | A    |
4  | B    |
4  | C    |
5  | A    |
5  | B    |
```

In R, how can I find the most frequent combinations of Items bought amongst my customers?

I've tried

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID,Item) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>% 
  top_n(3, Item) %>% 
  select(-n)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Can I get a dplyr solution?

dput:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5), Item = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 summarise(Item = paste(sort(unique(Item)), collapse = "")) %>%
 count(Item)

  Item      n
  <chr> <int>
1 AB        2
2 ABC       3
```

Comment: hi tmfmnk, your code seems to work. could you pls explain what's going on in your code esp the summarise part?

Comment: Sure. It takes the unique items per ID, sorts them and then pastes them together. So for every ID, there is a string of unique ordered values. Based on this, it performs the count.