# How can I identify the most frequent combinations of values within groups?

Tags: r, combinations

I have a table where each row represents the enrollment of one student in one course, similar to this, but much larger:

| Student | Course |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | PSYC101 |
| 001 | CHEM102 |
| 002 | PSYC101 |
| 002 | SPAN101 |
| 002 | BIO101 |
| 003 | BIO101 |
| 003 | ENG201 |
| 003 | HIND101 |
| 003 | CHEM102 |
| 004 | PSYC101 |
| 004 | CHEM102 |
| 004 | HIND101 |

I want to know which combinations of courses students most frequently take together. I'm starting with 2-course combinations, but may also want to look at 3-course combinations.

I am drawing a complete blank on what this procedure is called.

I found this similar example that uses the `dplyr` package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613192/r-how-to-find-the-most-frequent-combinations

However, I don't think this is exactly what I want. I want all of the possible 2-course combinations when some students have taken more than 2 courses. For example, for student 3, they would have the following:

- BIO101 & ENG201
- BIO101 & HIND101
- BIO101 & CHEM102
- ENG201 & HIND101
- ENG201 & CHEM102
- HIND101 & CHEM102

Then, I would find the most common combinations across all students.

Comment: For the 2-way, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77304051/9463489). The student is the salad, and the courses are the ingredients.

Comment: "*However, I get an error message when I run this code.*" What is the error? Where is the code? Please see [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A base R approach uses `combn` (choosing 2 elements) by Student to create the combinations of all of each particular student's course, then using `table` to see how often those pairs occur over the whole population.

I am going to put the combined code below, then tease out what's going on after that by breaking it down so its a bit more readable/understandable.

If you want to look at 3 course options, change `combn(x$Course, 2)` to `combn(x$Course, 3)` to select combinations of three.

```
table(apply(do.call(cbind, lapply(split(df, df$Student), \(x)
                                  combn(x$Course, 2))), 2, \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "_")))
```

Output

```
# BIO101_CHEM102   BIO101_ENG201  BIO101_HIND101 CHEM102_HIND101  ENG201_CHEM102  ENG201_HIND101 
#               1               1               1               1               1               1 

# HIND101_CHEM102  PSYC101_BIO101 PSYC101_CHEM102 PSYC101_HIND101 PSYC101_SPAN101  SPAN101_BIO101 
#               1               1               2               1               1               1
```

First, used `split` to break up the data frame (`df`) into a list by each student, then found combinations of courses, then combined and pasted combinations together, then made a table:

```
# Split by student
ll <- split(df, df$Student)

# find combinations of courses
combs_list <- lapply(ll, \(x) combn(unique(x$Course), 2))

# combine it into a matrix
combs_combined <- do.call(cbind, combs_list)

# paste combinations together
apply_combined <- apply(combs_combined, 2, \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "_"))

#make a table
table(apply_combined)
```

Note, if you want it in a data frame, simply wrap the table:

```
data.frame(tt)

# or to order by frequency:
data.frame(tt)[order(tt, decreasing = TRUE),]

#     apply_combined Freq
# 7  CHEM102_HIND101    2
# 8  CHEM102_PSYC101    2
# 1   BIO101_CHEM102    1
# 2    BIO101_ENG201    1
# 3   BIO101_HIND101    1
# ...
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Student    Course
001 PSYC101
001 CHEM102
002 PSYC101
002 SPAN101
002 BIO101
003 BIO101
003 ENG201
003 HIND101
003 CHEM102
004 PSYC101
004 CHEM102
004 HIND101", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can filter out students that have fewer rows than the `m` combination of interest, use `combn()` to generate the combinations, which are then transposed and row sorted, unpack the tibble, tally the results, then sort descending.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

n <- 2

dat %>%
  filter(n() >= n, .by = Student) %>%
  reframe(x = t(combn(Course, n)) %>%
            {matrix(.[order(row(.), .)], ncol = ncol(.), byrow = TRUE)} %>%
            as_tibble(), .by = Student) |>
  unpack(x) |>
  count(across(-Student)) |>
  arrange(-n)

# A tibble: 11 × 3
   V1      V2          n
   <chr>   <chr>   <int>
 1 CHEM102 HIND101     2
 2 CHEM102 PSYC101     2
 3 BIO101  CHEM102     1
 4 BIO101  ENG201      1
 5 BIO101  HIND101     1
 6 BIO101  PSYC101     1
 7 BIO101  SPAN101     1
 8 CHEM102 ENG201      1
 9 ENG201  HIND101     1
10 HIND101 PSYC101     1
11 PSYC101 SPAN101     1
```

For `n = 3` you will get:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  V1      V2      V3          n
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <int>
1 BIO101  CHEM102 ENG201      1
2 BIO101  CHEM102 HIND101     1
3 BIO101  ENG201  HIND101     1
4 BIO101  PSYC101 SPAN101     1
5 CHEM102 ENG201  HIND101     1
6 CHEM102 HIND101 PSYC101     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Another `dplyr` approach with `combn`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  arrange(Student, Course) |> 
  reframe(Course_comb = combn(seq_along(Student), 2, function(i) paste(Course[i], collapse = " & ")), .by = Student) |> 
  count(Course_comb, sort = TRUE)

#          Course_comb n
# 1  CHEM102 & PSYC101 2
# 2  CHEM102 & HIND101 2
# 3   BIO101 & PSYC101 1
# 4   BIO101 & SPAN101 1
# 5  PSYC101 & SPAN101 1
# 6   BIO101 & CHEM102 1
# 7    BIO101 & ENG201 1
# 8   BIO101 & HIND101 1
# 9   CHEM102 & ENG201 1
# 10  ENG201 & HIND101 1
# 11 HIND101 & PSYC101 1
```

Comment: I can get this to run, but the result is not the Course_comb, it's <named list [1]> in each row. I've done some searching and can't find any way to fix this. Any idea why it wouldn't be showing the actual Course_comb text?

Comment: Right. I edited it to avoid this problem, which was the use of `list` in `combn`

Comment: Thanks! This option works well for the 3- and 4-way combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of a more graphical approach...

```
df <- scale(table(df[,2], df[,1]))
# calculate distance between Courses
d <- dist(df, method = "euclidean")
# Hierarchical clustering 
clustered <- hclust(d, method = "complete" )
# Plot dendrogram
plot(clustered)
```

[image]

```
# load sample data
df <- read.table(text = "Student    Course
001 PSYC101
001 CHEM102
002 PSYC101
002 SPAN101
002 BIO101
003 BIO101
003 ENG201
003 HIND101
003 CHEM102
004 PSYC101
004 CHEM102
004 HIND101", header = TRUE)
```